# ISO8601 direct DateTime parse incorrect by single day

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass two datetime fields (start date and end date) to my webapi server in which the ISO8601 format date string in my javascript appears to be passing correctly, but the server is interpretting both dates incorrectly by a single day.

/service/api/application/2016-09-01T14:00:00.000Z/2016-09-30T13:59:59.999Z/

results in:

Start Date ='2016-09-02 00:00:00'

End Date = '2016-10-01 00:00:00'

```
[Route("api/Application/{dateLodgedStart}/{dateLodgedEnd}")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(PagedResultObject<ApplicationObject>))]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(DateTime? dateLodgedStart, DateTime? dateLodgedEnd) {
 //Do stuff
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What time zone are you in?

Comment: Both client and server are in GMT/UTC + 10:00. Would this be an issue even if there was a difference? If I am passing a date as a value, shouldn't that be used instead of trying to convert it to local time?

Comment: The `Z` at the end of those times indicates "Zulu time" or "GMT+0". So it's recognising that you're in GMT+10 and adding the 10 hours for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are in GMT+10 and you are parsing dates in "Zulu Time" - i.e. GMT+0 then the parser is automatically adding the 10 hours for you.

If we use C# for the parsing then we can see this using `DateTimeOffset.Parse`:

```
var startDate =
    DateTimeOffset
        .Parse("2016-09-01T14:00:00.000Z")
        .ToOffset(TimeSpan.FromHours(10.0));

var endDate =
    DateTimeOffset
        .Parse("2016-09-30T13:59:59.999Z")
        .ToOffset(TimeSpan.FromHours(10.0));            

Console.WriteLine(startDate);
Console.WriteLine(endDate);
```

This produces:

```
2016/09/02 00:00:00 +10:00
2016/09/30 23:59:59 +10:00
```

There does still appear to be an odd rounding error on your end date though.

Comment: Definitely put me in the right direction. On the Javascript side I was using toJson which turned my local time into UTC (which was 14th hour), then going to the web server it was changing it again to +10 and adding another 10 hours which pushed them across to the next day. Got it sorted now. Great help and good explanation.